# How correct sort not int numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

help please! I ran into a problem that when sorting numpy arrays by the second and third columns in descending order, it is impossible to do this because of that. Everything works until the code encounters numbers greater than 9. How can you solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZESu.png)

```
import numpy as np
data = [
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 5, 12, 16, 15, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 5, 7, 15, 20, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 4, 23, 16, 40, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 4, 20, 11, 15, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 4, 12, 17, 45, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 3, 26, 20, 45, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Offence Against a Person', 2015, 8, 11,'unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 0.000000, 0.000000],
    ['Break and Enter Residential/Other', 2003, 3, 10, 12, 0, 'Kerrisdale', 49.228051, -123.146610],
    ['Mischief', 2003, 6, 28, 4, 13, 'Dunbar-Southlands', 49.255559, -123.193725],
    ['Mischief', 2017, 3, 26, 23, 0, 'Sunset', 49.21431483, -123.101945],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 2, 16, 9, 2, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Break and Enter Residential/Other', 2003, 7, 9, 18, 15, 'Grandview-Woodland', 49.267734, -123.067654],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 1, 31, 19, 45, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Mischief', 2003, 9, 27, 1, 0, 'Dunbar-Southlands', 49.253762, -123.194407],
    ['Offence Against a Person', 2017, 1 , 24, 'unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 0.000000, 0.000000],
    ['Break and Enter Residential/Other', 2003, 4, 19, 18, 0, 'Grandview-Woodland', 49.267814, -123.067441],
    ['Break and Enter Residential/Other', 2003, 9, 24, 18, 30, 'Grandview-Woodland', 49.267731, -123.067302],
    ['Break and Enter Residential/Other', 2003, 11, 5, 8, 12, 'Sunset', 49.226430, -123.085283],
    ['Break and Enter Commercial', 2003, 9, 26, 2, 30, 'West End', 49.284715, -123.122824],
    ['Break and Enter Residential/Other', 2003, 10, 21, 10, 0, 'Grandview-Woodland', 49.267811, -123.067089],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 1, 25, 12, 30, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Offence Against a Person', 2003, 2, 12, 'unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 0.000000, 0.000000],
    ['Other Theft', 2003, 1, 9, 6, 45, 'Strathcona', 49.269802, -123.083763],
    ['Offence Against a Person', 2008, 2, 6, 'unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 0.000000, 0.000000],
]
np_array = np.array(data)
bool_column = np.int_(np.empty(np_array.shape[0]))
for line in range(np_array.shape[0]):
    if np_array[line,4] and np_array[line,5] == 'unknown':
        bool_column[line] = int(0)
    else:
        bool_column[line] = 1
np_array = np.append(np_array, np.reshape(bool_column,(np_array.shape[0],-1)), axis=1) #add bool col
#sort
np_array = np_array[np_array[:,2].argsort()]#month sort
np_array = np_array[np_array[:,1].argsort(kind='stable')[::-1]] #year sort with month
#count spaces foe nice data output
equals_spaces = []
temp_for_cicle = 0
for num_in_line in range(np_array.shape[1]):
    for line in range (np_array.shape[0]):
        if len(np_array[line][num_in_line]) > temp_for_cicle:
            temp_for_cicle = len(np_array[line][num_in_line])
    equals_spaces.append(temp_for_cicle)
    temp_for_cicle = 0
#data output
for line in range(np_array.shape[0]):
    for num_in_line in range (np_array.shape[1]):
        print('{:<{}}'.format(np_array[line][num_in_line],equals_spaces[num_in_line]), end='')
        if num_in_line+1 == np_array.shape[1]:
            print("")
        else:
            print(" | ", end='')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's the actual problem? Also, that's way too much code. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including minimal code, expected output, and actual output (or if you get an error, the full error message with traceback). You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: If you `print(np_array.dtype)`, you can see that the array's data type is a unicode string.

Comment: Why are you using numpy for tabular data? Use Pandas.

Comment: `idx = np_array[:,2].astype(int).argsort()` might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the sort before converting to numpy, and skip the `numpy.argsort` calls, it works:

```
data.sort( key=lambda row: (-row[1], -row[2]) )
np_array = np.array(data)
```

The advise to use `pandas` is probably the best advice.

Comment: Well, thanks, I remembered about the pandas!
This assignment is from the course and there they asked to do everything using numpy. I have been looking for a solution for a long time on how to change the data type for normal sorting in only one column, but none of the solutions helped me.

I'll use your solution, I didn't think of sorting everything in advance, thanks!